# Slide show with different slide times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***EDIT:***

I'm currently working with the anwser of Louys Patrice Besette, and i'm almost done with putting all the slides in. 
However sometimes when i refresh the page. The video becomes black and does not play. And this goes on for all the next upcomming videos. And then a few refreshes later it works again.

Why does this happen?

I get this error in the console when the error (black videos) happen: index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Also one more question. Is the a way to make like a waiting line for the things to be loaded?
I'm on about 60-70% now of being finished with the site. However, i notice that my laptop has to work very very very hard in order to load all the videos and images for the first time.

***End of EDIT***

Right now i'm trying to make a kind of slide show to display Images and Videos one by one.

My code so far looks like this:

### Html:

```
<div id="div1" class="hidden">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
<div id="div3" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
<div id="div4" class="hidden">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="div5" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
<div id="div6" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
<div id="div7" class="hidden">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="div8" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
<div id="div9" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
```

This code collects 9 "slides". 3 videos and 7 images.
I want to show these one by one on the web page (each displaying for a different time).

I do this by:

### Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //show first slide
    function showIt() {
        document.getElementById("div1").className = "shown";
    }
    setTimeout("showIt()", 0000);

    //Start fading first slide
    function hideIt() {
        document.getElementById("div1").className = "fade";
    }
    setTimeout("hideIt()", 16000);

    //Start showing 2nd slide
    function showIt2() {
        document.getElementById("div2").className = "shown";
    }
    setTimeout("showIt2()", 16500);

    //Remove the first slide
    function removeIt() {
        document.getElementById("div1").className = "hidden";
    }
    setTimeout("removeIt()", 17000);

    //Start fading second slide
    function hideIt2() {
        document.getElementById("div2").className = "fade";
    }
    setTimeout("hideIt2()", 27000);

    //Remove the second slide
    function removeIt2() {
        document.getElementById("div1").className = "hidden";
    }
    setTimeout("removeIt2()", 28000);

    //When end is reached, reload page
    setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 28000);
</script>
```

### And the Css:

```
img {
    max-width: 78%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 10.5%;
}

video {
    max-width: 78%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 10.5%;
}

.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fade{
    -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadeout 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}


.shown{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

As you can see, i'm only displaying 2 slides right now. while i have 9 ready. (in total i have got 40+). If i keep going the way i go right now. i will get tons and tons of code...

### Question:

> Is there a way to make this more compact/smaller?
>
> I searched the internet for slideshows and find things. However i want
>   to set the time to be seen for each slide. Since some slides need to
>   be displayed 20 seconds and other 10.

Also i made a fiddle, but it is not working in there...
https://jsfiddle.net/a10yarxj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, in your question, that you want to have full control over the slideshow timings.
The display time...
And I added the possibility for fade in/out times to be different aswell.

The slides will contain image or video, wich may be longer than your timing... Letting the sound continue while other slides are displayed.

I suppose that the image/video order may (and will!) change over time...
And that the slide amount is variable.

**So I made this small script that you will not have to modify** each time you change the slideshow content.
All params are provided in the HTML:

- data-timing *(time in seconds)*
- data-fadein *(time in seconds)*
- data-fadeout *(time in seconds)*
- data-videopause *(true/false)*

For the 3 first parameters, if the value is missing, default time is applyed and a «NOTICE» is shown in `console.log()`.
For the last, if it is missing, it will be considered false.

I used jQuery `.animate()` instead of CSS `@keyframes` because the effect is easier to achieve this way, since only the `opacity` is affected.

The slideshow is looping... So no need for a new page load at the end.

Here it is, in the below snippet and on [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xEYzpg?editors=1011):

**EDIT**
I added a `setTimeout` "bugfix" on lines 8 to 12 and on line 54.
As per below comments, it appears that a `setTimeout` may remain in DOM on page refresh [F5].
To prevent that, we clear it if it exist.

```js
var slides = $(".slide");
var lastSlideIndex = slides.length-1;
var currentSlideIndex = 0;
var defaultTiming = 1000;
var defaultFadeInTime = 1000;
var defaultFadeOutTime = 1000;

// Prevents a setTimeout to remain in browser cache on page refresh.
if (typeof slideTimer !== 'undefined') {
  clearTimeout(slideTimer);
}
var slideTimer;

// Show slide function
function showSlide() {
    
 var thisSlide = slides.eq(currentSlideIndex);
 
 // Delays
 var timing = parseFloat(thisSlide.attr("data-timing")) * 1000; // Transform seconds in milliseconds
 if(isNaN(timing)){timing=defaultTiming; console.log("NOTICE: ----------- data-timing is missing, using default.");}
 var fadeInTime = parseFloat(thisSlide.attr("data-fadein")) * 1000;
 if(isNaN(fadeInTime)){fadeInTime=defaultFadeInTime; console.log("NOTICE: ----------- data-fadein is missing, using default.");}
 var fadeOutTime = parseFloat(thisSlide.attr("data-fadeout")) * 1000;
 if(isNaN(fadeOutTime)){fadeOutTime=defaultFadeOutTime; console.log("NOTICE: ----------- data-fadeout is missing, using default.");}
 
    console.log("Slide: "+currentSlideIndex+":\n Display time: "+timing+" millisec.\n Fadein: "+fadeInTime+" millisec.\n Fadeout: "+fadeOutTime+" millisec.");
    thisSlide.animate({"opacity":1},fadeInTime);
    
 // If this slide contains a video
 if(slides.eq(currentSlideIndex).find("video").length > 0){
  
  // Prevents more than 1 video to play at the same time
  $("video").each(function(){
   console.log("All video paused.")
   $(this)[0].pause();
  });
  
  // Play this video from the start
  var thisVideo = slides.eq(currentSlideIndex).find("video")[0];
  thisVideo.currentTime = 0;
  console.log("Video playing.");
  thisVideo.play()
 }
 
    // Prepare for next slide
    currentSlideIndex++;
 
 // Reset to slide 0 if last was reached
    if(currentSlideIndex>lastSlideIndex){
        currentSlideIndex=0;
    }
    
    slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        // Fade out previous slide
  var previousSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex-1;
  
  
  // If previous was last slide
  if(previousSlideIndex == -1){
   previousSlideIndex = lastSlideIndex;
  }
  
  // If previous slide was set to pause
  if(slides.eq(previousSlideIndex).attr("data-videopause")=="true"){
   console.log("Video has been paused.");
   slides.eq(previousSlideIndex).find("video")[0].pause();
  }
  
  slides.eq(previousSlideIndex).animate({"opacity":0},fadeOutTime);
        showSlide();
    }, timing);
}

// Init
showSlide();
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 78%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 10.5%;
}

video {
    max-width: 78%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 10.5%;
}

.slide{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide" data-timing=4 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=1 data-videopause=false>
    <video>
        <source src="https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/39920322/video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=4 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=0.5><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Fritz_von_Wille_0071.jpg" /></div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=2 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=1><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Truncated_View_of_the_Broekzijdse_Molen_on_the_Gein_by_Piet_Mondrian.jpg" /></div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=6 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=2 data-videopause=true>
    <video>
        <source src="https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/39920322/video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=2 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=3><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Walter_Leistikow_-_Liebesinsel_(1905).jpg" /></div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=4 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=1><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%90._%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96.jpg" /></div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=6 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=0.5 data-videopause=true>
    <video>
        <source src="https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/39920322/video-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=3 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=1><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Morris21.jpg" /></div>
<div class="slide" data-timing=2 data-fadein=0.5 data-fadeout=2><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Fritz_von_Wille_0071.jpg" /></div>



<!-- ---------------------------
Copyright issues:
Images used here are labelled for reuse and videos were made by me for this example.

The Google image search I used: https://www.google.ca/search?q=paysage&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=1110&tbs=islt:svga,isz:ex,iszw:500,iszh:400&tbm=isch&source=lnt#tbs=islt:svga%2Cisz:ex%2Ciszw:500%2Ciszh:400%2Csur:fc&tbm=isch&q=landscape+-flickr&imgrc=pqMMLvfhjtbSuM%3A

 -->
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Will take a look through all the awnsers, but this looks much promising! I will try this one.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Also understand it right now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm currently working with this, and i'm almost done with putting all the slide in. However sometimes when i refresh the page. The video becomes black and does not play. And this goes on for all the next upcomming videos. And then a few refreshes later it works again. Why does this happen? 

Also i get this error in the console when the error (black videos) happen:
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

@Louys Patrice Besette

Comment: This is probably caused by the `setTimeout` still in cache even on refresh. I don't think it is a "normal behavior" to refresh the page often... You do it because you are testing your page. Try testing it by pressing [ctrl]+[F5] simultaneously instead of only [F5]. It reloads the page, and also clears the cache. If you think your users may encounter this too... I will edit my answer with a fix.

Comment: Okay... I made the edit anyway... Please, tell me if this is eficiently working on your side ;)

Comment: This is working :) It's slow the first time, but that's because it needs to load all of the videos and images etc. 

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have add only one function call with timeout. You can add time of your slide directly in table. Please try

```js
var totalSlide =[0,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000];
var slideStart = 0;
showIt();

function showIt() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var idNow = document.getElementById("div"+(slideStart+1));
    idNow.className = "shown";
    
    slideStart++;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      idNow.className = "fade";
      setTimeout(function(){idNow.className = "hidden";},500)
     if(slideStart == totalSlide.length-1 ){
          slideStart = 0;
        }
        showIt()
    },totalSlide[slideStart])
  }, 0)
}
```

```css
img {
 max-width: 78%;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left: 10.5%;
}

video {
 max-width: 78%;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left: 10.5%;
}

.hidden{
 visibility: hidden;
}

.fade{
 -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadeout 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}


.shown{
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="hidden">
   <video autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="div3" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="div4" class="hidden">
   <video autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
  <div id="div5" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="div6" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="div7" class="hidden">
   <video autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
  <div id="div8" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
  <div id="div9" class="hidden"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></div>
```

UPDATE

```
var video = $(".div7").find("video");

function playVid() {
    video .play();
}

function pauseVid() {
    video .pause();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. 

I have tryed this, and it is working. However the movies already started playing while the div is still hidden.

So after i have seen like 3 slide shows, the movies don't play anymore because they are already done.

Comment: Yes you can loop the video with the parameter loop : `<video autoplay loop>` or you can add a javascript function play and stop. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. From a pure javascript perspective, this is a quick solution but it can be improved further (that can be your job):

```
(function() {
    var currentDivNumber = 1;
    function removeIt() {
        document.getElementById("div"+currentDivNumber).className = "hidden";
        currentDivNumber++;
        if ( currentDivNumber > maxSlides) {
            currentDivNumber=1;
        }
        setTimeout(showIt, 500);
    }

    function hideIt() {
        document.getElementById("div"+currentDivNumber).className = "fade";
        setTimeout(removeIt, 500);
    }
    function showIt() {
        document.getElementById("div"+currentDivNumber).className = "shown";
        setTimeout(hideIt, 500);
    }

    setTimeout(showIt, 16000);
})();
```

This is not optimal it can be further improved. Plus maybe better CSS can be used to remove additional if not all javascript?

see : https://jsfiddle.net/0mvpfthL/1/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

> [...] However i want to set the time to be seen for each slide. Since some slides need to be displayed 20 seconds and other 10.

You can use `data` attribute to store *duration* time of each slide:

```
<div id="div1" data-duration="3500" class="hidden">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Then (using jQuery), you could combine `setTimeout`'s for each action (each class toggle). Use `class` instead of `id`:

```
var durations = 0;
var play = function(){
  var that = $(this), i = that.index(), duration = that.data('duration'), l = $('.hidden').length;
  setTimeout(function(){
    that.toggleClass('hidden shown');
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.toggleClass('shown fade');
      setTimeout(function(){
        that.toggleClass('fade hidden');
        if(i+1 === l){
          // No need to reload page. If you want to loop over again, uncomment this:
          // $('.hidden').each(play);
        }
      }, 500);
    }, duration);
  }, durations);
  durations += duration+500;
}

$('.hidden').each(play);
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hxooukga/2/)</kbd>